# Css code must don't apply on a tag

Tags: html, css

hi this is my CSS code

```
    #imageUploadArea input
{
    width:70px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

i want this tag

```
<input type="button" value="submit" class="imagePickerBtn" id="imageUploadSubmit">
```

don't use that CSS codes

Comment: please, rephrase your question so that it is more clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Ehm .. remove the `id` from the input?

Comment: `#imageUploadArea input:not(#imageUploadSubmit)` ?

Comment: Where's the question here? I don't understand what you need

Comment: thanks a lot this is works Sirko understand me

Answer (score 1):

You could try rewrite this selector like below

`#imageUploadArea input:not(#imageUploadSubmit) { }`

That selector will style every input inside `#imageUploadArea` except your button with id `#imageUploadSubmit`

Answer (score -2):

This code works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
 .imageUploadArea
{
    width:70px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="submit" class="imageUploadArea" id="imageUploadSubmit">

</body>
</html>
```